# What is the root of the word ואורשנו in Bamidbar 14:12

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, parashat-shelach

What is the root of the word וְאוֹרִשֶׁנּוּ in this verse.?

> אַכֶּנּוּ בַדֶּבֶר **וְאוֹרִשֶׁנּוּ** וְאֶעֱשֶׂה אֹתְךָ לְגוֹי גָּדוֹל וְעָצוּם מִמֶּנּוּ

Comment: Do you know what the conjugated form means? Do you have any guesses? What have you checked? Please [edit] to clarify so we can better help you.

Comment: Guys. We’ve been over this before. Asking about words in Tanach is on-topic here. However, I do agree with DoubleAA that this could use a little more research, but that doesn’t make it closeworthy under the current guidelines as I understand them. It’s certainly not unclear what it’s looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I, too was puzzled by the use of this term, here, and [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.14.12?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) translates this as "destroy", which is not the usual translation of this word.

However, based on what I see in Haamek Davar on Numbers 14:12:2:

ואורישנו.

> אין הפי׳ ואורישנו אליך. והיאך יעלה עה״ד להרוג טף ונשים ועוד כמה צדיקים
>   שלא חטאו גם שבט לוי.
>
> **אלא ה״פ ואורישנו לבניהם שישארו הטף במדבר עד שיגדלו ויכבשו א״י וכ״כ הספורנו:**

I shall translate just the bold part at the end:

The meaning is "I will cause it to be inherited to their children in the manner that the young ones will remain in the land until they grow older and they shall conquer the land of Israel.

Thus, the root word is ירש - to inherit. אורישנו is in the הפעיל form.

Comment: That is what the Seforno says here as well, but Rashi says explicitly that it is not from the Shoresh of Yerusha.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Indeed. Do you know what Rash"i is saying? I don't understand the word that he uses.

Comment: תירוכין is Targum for גירושין. It means they will be chased away. Rashi doesn't explain the Shoresh, though